# Chart.js Show Label near Line in combined Chart

Tags: charts, label, chart.js

I have a combined BarLineChart. Is there a possibility to add a label near the line (in this case how much the sales increased from 2015 to 2016) ?

I hope there is some way

[This is what i have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApeTQ.png)

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf9RC.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) plugin provided by the same team that provides chart.js.

You can use the plugin to draw arbitrary lines or boxes on your chart that can also contain a label.  Unfortunately, the plugin does not yet support point annotations, so you have to use a little hack to enable the label to display but not the line or box.

Here is an example chart that uses the plugin to draw a horizontal white line at a specific Y value (white is used so that it blends in with the chart background and becomes invisible).  The line is configured to also have a label.  The end result is a text annotation on the chart with no visible line.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Jan 21st', 'Feb 21st'],
    datasets: [{
      type: 'line', 
      label: 'B',
      data: [10, 25],
      fill: false,
      borderWidth: 3,
      borderColor: chartColors.orange,
      lineTension: 0,
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'A',
      backgroundColor: chartColors.blue,
      data: [10, 25],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],  
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 'Jan 21st',
          max: 'Apr 21st',
        }
      }],
    },
    annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: 18,
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 0,
        label: {
          xAdjust: -50,
          fontSize: 16,
          fontColor: 'black',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          content: "+20%",
          enabled: true
        }
      }],
      drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw'
    }
  }
});
```

You can see it in action at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/BWboLy).

One final note, if you include the plugin in your app and you also use charts that don't use scales (e.g. pie/doughnut) then you will get an error.  This is a known issue and has been logged [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/issues/49).

The workaround is to add this to your pie/doughnut chart config (or it might be easier to add it to the pie/doughnut global default config).

```
scales:{
  yAxes: [],
  xAxes: []
},
```

Comment: Hey this looks promising, but if i implement the annotations plugin i get an error message saying: Cannot read property 'xAxes' of undefined. I have multiple Charts on my Page currently this error is showing for my Pie Chart.

Comment: Did you try to add the `annotation` property to your global configuration or something?  That won't work in your case because pie/doughnut charts do not have a scale and therefore the annotation plugin will not work with those chart types.

Comment: Yes i just imported the file into html, so is there some kind of workaround so that i can still use the other charts?

Comment: Looks like this is an [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/issues/49) already logged in github.  I will update my answer with a work around until it is fixed.